# www subdomain links to a fresh Laravel application on a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess

I have a website `http://neurosensum.com` and we want to open non `www` urls always so we added following code in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but when we hit URL with `http://www.neurosensum.com` we are getting Laravel screen. However, this website is not using Laravel. How to resolve this now?

Comment: Are you using https://forge.laravel.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just pinged the domain with and without `www`

```
~ ✹ ★ ᐅ  ping www.neurosensum.com
PING www.neurosensum.com (52.221.226.126) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.neurosensum.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

~ ✹ ★ ᐅ  ping neurosensum.com    
PING neurosensum.com (13.250.116.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ec2-13-250-116-128.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (13.250.116.128): icmp_seq=1 ttl=236 time=307 ms
^C
--- neurosensum.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 307.176/307.176/307.176/0.000 ms
```

The `www` subdomain is pointing to a different IP address

```
neurosensum.com ========> 13.250.116.128
www.neurosensum.com ====> 52.221.226.126
```

So change your DNS settings in the domain provider to make `www` an alias of the main domain or an A record pointing to `13.250.116.128`

Since you're hosting the site on an Amazon EC2 instance, you may create a CNAME alias record for `www` through `Route 53` by [following the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-create-alias-records/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated the same DNS records but still it's not redirecting. We updated A record pointing www.neurosensum.com ====> 13.250.116.128

Comment: You have to wait for DNS propagation to finish, may take a while, see here https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.neurosensum.com